# How to solve the ModuleNotFoundError when using auto-py-to-exe?

Tags: python, pysimplegui, modulenotfounderror, auto-py-to-exe

I tried to convert a .py to .exe, but a traceback is occurring when the .exe is opened, showing this message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Desformatador_1.0.py", line
> 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySimpleGUI'

The app run normally on VSCode as .py, but the same isn't true when converted...
I already tried to use the hidden import in auto-py-to-exe, filling the input with PySimpleGUI.
I also tried to paste the PySimpleGUI fold into my app directory, It didn't work as well.
Well, I'm new into the programming world and was very excited when I finally wrote some useful code, but this traceback really have been a thorn in my side.
(I'm using Windows 10 and Anaconda Prompt.)

Comment: Maybe try the psgcompiler application made by the PySimpleGUI project as another way to make youre EXE file?

Comment: As I looked again, I see "Anaconda Prompt", which I think is the core of your problem, but it's just an opinion/guess.

Answer (score 2):

The psgcompiler app solved the problem, thanks Mike!

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you're up and running!  Thanks for letting others know it's one solution among many for creating an EXE from your Python code.